# add mousewheel event to absolute panel

Tags: gwt, mousewheel

can we add a mousewheel event to absolute panel in GWT. I have added a mousewheel event to absolute panel but it is not working .Why this problem is there but if I add it to label then its working properly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the AbsolutePanel does not implements the HasAllMouseHandlers interface specifically HasMouseWheelHandlers. Label implements HasMouseWheelHandlers interface. So it works for Label.

You have to extend AbsolutePanel and implement HasMouseWheelHandlers interface to make it work with AbsolutePanel. And behavior you have to define.

```
public class MyAbsolutePanel extends AbsolutePanel implements HasMouseWheelHandlers 
{
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseWheelHandler(MouseWheelHandler handler) 
    {  
        // Define the behavior here.
       return addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType());  
    }  
}
```